# How to properly implement filters and/or projections in MongoDB with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, filtering

I have a very simple document(row) structure in a collection(table) - named `user_records` like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("652edd74bdb84c9944d280d6"),
    customer_id: 1001,
    first_name: 'Test',
    last_name: 'User',
    username: 'Tuser',
    password: 'Testuser',
    registration_date: 2023-10-17T13:54:54.000Z
  }
]
```

I want to run a query that returns just the `customer ID`, `first name`, `last name` and `username`, where `username` = `username`. However, all the queries I have tried just return the full document(row).

My first attempt was this one, largely inspired by the MongoDB Compass AI:

1. I defined the filter and projections parameters for the query:

```
// Define query parameters
const filter = { 'username': username };
const projections = {
        '_id': 0,
        'customer_id': 1,
        'first_name': 1, 
        'last_name': 1, 
        'username': 1,
        'password': 0,
        'registration_date': 0
};
```

2. I built the query:

```
const customersCollection = client.db('customer_data').collection('user_records');

const customer = await customersCollection.find(filter, projections).toArray();
```

In attempting to get this to work, I also tried some modifications:

- Removing the `''` from the keys in the projection object.
- Passing `projections` as an object to `.find`. So like `.find(filter, { projections })`.
- Using `findOne` instead.

None of the above worked.

My second attempt was even more complex. Instead of defining a `projections` object, I just did this:

```
const customersCollection = client.db('customer_data').collection('user_records');

const customer = await customersCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: filter },
    {
      $project: {
        '_id': 0,
        'customer_id': 1,
        'first_name': 1, 
        'last_name': 1, 
        'username': 1,
        'password': 0,
        'registration_date': 0
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();
```

This didn't return anything.

In all this, I was just trying to get `customer` to hold this:

```
[
  {
    customer_id: 1001,
    first_name: 'Test',
    last_name: 'User',
    username: 'Tuser',
  }
]
```

I only started working with MongoDB a few days ago, coming from MySQL; any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I think we need more debugging details.

Assuming that the `username` variable in your first attempt is set to the string `'Tuser'`, it does not even run since it mixes up 'inclusion' and 'exclusion' projections. You can see the error in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7XjfNZaA7jy).

We don't know what your `filter` variable was in your second attempt. If I assume that it is similarly `{ username: 'Tuser' }`, then it too fails with the same error due to the malformed projection. You can see that in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j__aMK1CLuP).

Are you certain that the (recompiled?) code/queries that you are sharing is what is getting sent to the database?

In any case, what you want is to do an [inclusion projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only) while also [suppressing the `_id` field](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-_id-field). This entails removing the final two lines from your projection, e.g.:

```
db.collection.find({
  "username": "Tuser"
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "customer_id": 1,
  "first_name": 1,
  "last_name": 1,
  "username": 1
})
```

When you run that query against a collection with these two documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("652edd74bdb84c9944d280d6"),
    customer_id: 1001,
    first_name: "Test",
    last_name: "User",
    username: "Tuser",
    password: "Testuser",
    registration_date: new Date("2023-10-17T13:54:54.000Z")
  },
  {
    username: "other"
  }
]
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 1001,
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "User",
    "username": "Tuser"
  }
]
```

This seems to be what you were requesting. See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-0axbpC-uDX).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Although it didn't exactly work, your links and references were really helpful and it was through them I discovered that I also had to do `db.database.find({}).project(ions)({}).sort({})...`, which was the final structure of the query that I ended up with. 

As for `.project(ions)`, its weird because in Mongosh,`.project()` did not work, but `.projections()` did, however in my Node.js environment it was the opposite. I thought NoSQL was supposed to be easier than SQL

Comment: What driver, libraries, and/or tools (along with their versions) are you using? The syntax or interface for each can be a little different so you should focus your efforts to one at a time. You can see, for example, that at the top of [this page about `db.collection.find()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) that there is a note about it being relevant for the shell but not necessarily all of the drivers.